# Java - draw 18 rectangles separated by 20 degree angle

Tags: java, trigonometry

Write an applet that draws the rectangles (use fillPolygon() function) turned by angle 
ALPHA  relatively to the previous rectangle. Center of rotation is a one corner of a rectangle. ALPHA is equal to 20 degree, one side of rectangle is equal to 30 and other side is equal to 50. Amount of rectangles is equal to 18.

Please i need help in calculating coordinates of rectangle corners for fillPolygon function
unfortunately my trigonometry is very poor. and i dont have even any idea how to find these corners

i attach link for my homework  it is Task2. Thanks for help

http://staff.neu.edu.tr/~aamircanov/COM442Ass.pdf

Comment: Please at least show what you've tried. StackOverflow won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Hint: you don't need any trigonometry for this, because the Graphics2D of the applet is able to rotate. Rotate the Graphics2D by 20 degrees, draw your rectangle, repeat.

Comment: I don't need full answer i just need hint to start like small function which will calculate coordinates of only one maxsimum two corners. rest i will do myself. I cant even start withour this hint, because of poor trigonometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to perform a `rotate` transformation. Each class extending the abstract class `Graphics2D` implements a method like this.

Just insert appropriate code in the `paint` method of your applet. You'll need a combination of `drawRect` (or `fillPolygon` as your teacher wishes), `translate` and `rotate` methods.

Check out the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double%29